# Multi-module maven : test coverage jacoco sonar

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

I have a basic maven multi-module, with a parent being the POM and three children modules : domain, service and web.

I have added in the pom parent the jacoco plugin and the required configuration to append the test coverage report to a single file easily located by sonar.

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
   <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>0.6.2.201302030002</version>
   <configuration>
     <destFile>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
     <append>true</append> 
   </configuration>
   <executions>
    <execution>
     <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
     <goals>
      <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
     </goals>
    </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

My issue is that Sonar shows only the test coverage of the first module (being domain) (even though I open the file with an editor and I see the class names of the others modules being append in it.

What could wrong in this configuration ?

For what it's worth, sonar analysis is called from Jenkins, and not from mvn sonar:sonar

Comment: Why do you add jacoco-maven-plugin to your POM? Sonar does not require any additional plugins. It works fine with existing POMs without any modifications

Comment: @orionll I add the plugin and especially for the configuration in order to append the jacoco.exec files of each in module into a single one in the parent forlder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins configuration is the key : There is no need to append everything in a single file when the configuration is right.

I added this to the config :

```
sonar.modules=xxx-domain,xxx-service,xxx-web
```

and I deleted the configuration tag in the pom.xml given in the question.

It works like a charm

For those who struggle with this, look for anything useful to specify the jenkins project configuration for sonar

Comment: This means that you're analysis your project with a FreeStyle job instead of a Maven job with a Sonar Post Build Action?? If so, can you please explain why?

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam The configuration is like this : Jenkins doing continuous integration by building maven modules. I dont want my modules to know anything about sonar.

Answer (score 0):

You can check our sample application here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/ut/maven/ut-maven-jacoco-runTests

You should be able to find what's wrong with your configuration then.

Comment: the example provided is not for multi modules in maven.

Comment: Plus I specified I was running sonar from jenkins and not from mvn sonar:sonar

Comment: Well, we're analysing Sonar code base on a Jenkins server using the Sonar Jenkins Plugin and we haven't specified anything special in the POMs. And it uses the same configuration as the example I gave you. So this should work out if the box for you w/o the need to configure the JaCoCo Maven plugin like you did => no need to append all the jacoco.exec files into a single one.

Comment: Exactly, the configuration in Jenkins was the key. I add the solution below so everyone can read it